# Loading so files with dlsym, cannot load library

Tags: c++, plugins, shared-libraries, dlsym

I am implementing an API which loads plug-ins from .so files. To load them I am using the dlsym() function. To check if it works I have implemented a test plug-in (below) and to make things easier I am loading only the "initialize" function. To compile my code I am firstly creating the .so file with the following command:

```
      g++ -Wall -shared -rdynamic -fPIC plugin_test.cpp -o plugin_test.so
```

After that I run the plugin_manager.cpp as follows:

```
      g++ plugin_manager.cpp -o -plugin_manager.o -ldl
```

But after running the a.out and typing the correct filename, I get an error that I cannot load the .so file. Does anyone have a clue about how to solve this issue?

plugin_manager.cpp

```
      #include <dlfcn.h>
      #include <stdio.h>
      #include <stdlib.h>
      #include <string>
      #include <iostream>
      #include "plugin_interface.h"
      using namespace std;
      //typedef void (*test_function)(void);

      int main(void) {
       const char *error;
       void *module;
       //test_function initialize_test;
       //void (*initialize_test) (void);
       //test_function analyze_test;
       //test_function finalize_test;
       //load the DL library
       string filename;
       cout << "File :: " << endl;
       cin >> filename;
       module = dlopen(filename.c_str(), RTLD_LAZY);
       if (!module) {
           fprintf(stderr, "ERROR! Couldn't load library: %s\n",
           dlerror());
           exit(1);
       }

        //get and check symbol
        dlerror();
        initialize_f* initialize_function = (initialize_f*) dlsym(module, "initialize");
        if ((error = dlerror())) {
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR %s\n", error);
        exit(1);
        }

        //create instance of the class
        PluginInterface* plugin = initialize_function();

        //use the class
        plugin->initialize();
        //call "initialize" function from the test plug-in
        //(*initialize_test)();

        dlclose(module); //close the DL library
        return 0;
        }
```

plugin_interface.h

```
    #ifndef PLUGIN_INTERFACE_H_INCLUDED
    #define PLUGIN_INTERFACE_H_INCLUDED

    class PluginInterface{

    public:
        virtual void initialize() = 0;
        virtual void analyze() = 0;
        virtual void finalize() = 0;
    };

    //Definition of the pointer
    typedef PluginInterface* initialize_f();
    #endif // PLUGIN_INTERFACE_H_INCLUDED
```

test_plugin.cpp

```
         #include <iostream>
         #include "plugin_interface.h"
         using namespace std;

         class bbb :public PluginInterface {
           public:

         virtual void initialize(){
         cout << "Initialization";
         }

         void analyze(){
         cout << "Analysis";
         } 
         void finalize(){
         cout << "Finalization";
         }

         };

         //The functions we load must be qualified as extern "C" to avoid the symbol name being mangled
         extern "C" PluginInterface* initialize(){
         return new bbb();
         }
         int main()
         {


         //bbb* a = maker();
         //a->initialize();
         //Creating an instance and calling the "initialize" function with in
         PluginInterface* p = initialize();
         p->initialize(); 


         return 0;
         }
```

Comment: Have you tried the full path name or are you using a relative pathname.

Comment: Yep, tried both. I failed to compile [Example 2](http://www.faqs.org/docs/Linux-mini/C++-dlopen.html#loadingfunctions) as well. I think I am not using the correct commands

Comment: How do you compile? How do you test?

Comment: Does the file live on your LD_LIBRARY_PATH?

Comment: I have written the commands I use above. I firstly create the .so, then run the plugin_manager.

Comment: What do you mean by that @cup? Sorry I don't have a lot of experience.

Comment: As @Basile Starynkevitch says, add a . to the end of your LD_LIBRARY_PATH i.e from the cmd line, export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=.:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Comment: @cup: adding `.`  in *front* of `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`  is a huge security risk...., it should at least be put at end of `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`

Comment: Problem solved, I had one "/" in the file path forgotten. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read *carefully* and several times the [dlopen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html) man page.

When the flle path does not contain any `/` some specific processing happens.

You should `dlopen`  a path like `./foo.so` (otherwise add `.`  at the end of your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`  environment variable, but this might open a security risk, so I don't advise doing that)

(always test against `NULL`  result both  `dlopen`  and `dlsym` function calls  and display `dlerror()`  on failure)

BTW, your plugin manager should be compiled with:

```
      g++ -Wall -g plugin_manager.cpp -o -plugin_manager -ldl
```

Don't mention `plugin_manager.o`

Comment: Thanks fot the tip, but I tried it this way as well, and got the same result.. Even with the full file-path it failed to work. I actually tried running the Example 2 code from [here](http://www.faqs.org/docs/Linux-mini/C++-dlopen.html#loadingfunctions) and got the same error

Comment: Problem solved, I had one "/" in the file path forgotten. Thanks guys!